Can I replace my 1 TB Fusion Drive HDD with a new SSD without splitting the Fusion Drive first ? (because splitting is not possible)
I have a late 2015 27'' iMac with 1TB Fusion Drive. Normally I was using my macOS through an SSD connected to the USB and I was sooo happy about the performance of my computer. One day it restarted itself while in sleep mode and... never be able to start again;
Symptoms:
Apple logo appears when I connect my iOS containing external SSD, but the progress bar never fills up (it stays blank forever)
Question mark appears when I do not connect my external SSD with iOS.
Command+R does not work and OPT+Command+R do not continue after some point during start up
Apple diagnostics say my computer is ok
I resetted my NVRAM and tried all possible startup key combinations including Command+S (I cannot reach to Terminal (some weird data log appears and no place to write a command)
Apple authorized service cannot do anything since my computer is considered as vintage
I talked to the apple expert, and he said most probably my HDD is dead (it is silent now and I do not hear it anymore).
Do above symptoms root from the dead HDD?, even all my iOS data is in my external SSD?
Will replacing my internal HDD to a new internal SSD solve the problem?
I cannot split my Fusion Drive since I cannot reach to the Terminal app, will that be a problem?
What symptoms do you think I will have right after replacing my HDD with a new Sata3 SSD?
I like my computer and want it back, thanks to all in advance

If the HDD is broken and you indeed booted from an external SSD before, replacing the HDD with an SSD should work. Recommend to not rebuild the Fusion Drive though (doesn‘t make much sense with two internal SSDs).

But, if you can still boot into Internet Recovery, what can you find out there about the state of the internal disks?

If your hard drive failed, then the Fusion Drive is broken beyond repair.
You have a hard drive that doesn't work, and an internal SSD (probably only 20Gb!) that is now "unformatted".
You cannot get any data from the old Fusion drive.
You can replace the hard drive with a new SSD: you will then need to format the internal SSD for macOS.
Or you could just keep using the external SSD.
